# How to group and order rows with different date values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a result like this:

```
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+
|           Date            | InvoiceID |  Amount    |
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+
| 2020-06-09 12:36:37.433   | AF-1      | 189,876996 |
| 2020-06-09 12:36:37.483   | AF-1      | 59,4       |
| 2020-06-09 12:36:37.490   | AF-1      | 15,8544    |
| 2020-06-09 12:37:42.790   | AF-2      | 20,2       |
| 2020-06-09 12:39:29.453   | AF-4      | 70,6596    |
| 2020-06-09 12:43:30.553   | SF-1      | 47,1064    |
| 2020-06-09 12:43:30.577   | SF-1      | 12,96      |
| 2020-06-09 12:43:30.583   | SF-1      | 17,3664    |
| 2020-06-09 12:44:51.963   | SF-3      | 34,3905    |
| 2020-06-09 12:49:34.147   | TM-1      | 500        |
| 2020-06-09 12:50:26.040   | TM-2      | 150        |
| 2020-06-09 12:50:26.063   | TM-2      | 600        |
| 2020-06-09 12:51:29.817   | GH-1      | 500        |
| 2020-06-09 12:51:29.823   | GH-1      | 313,68     |
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Query is pretty simple:

```
Select Date, InvoiceID, Amount from TableName order by Date
```

I need to group them, get sum of amount and order by date. Notice that date values are not the same. I can't group results because of this. Important thing is i need to order by Date column. This is the result i want:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| InvoiceID |   Amount    |
+-----------+-------------+
| AF-1      | 265,131396  |
| AF-2      | 20,2        |
| AF-4      | 70,6596     |
| SF-1      | 77,4328     |
| SF-3      | 34,3905     |
| TM-1      | 500         |
| TM-2      | 750         |
| GH-1      | 813,68      |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I'm trying this code but sql gave me an error that i need to use Date column in group by clause.

```
SELECT InvoiceID, sum(Amount) as Amount from TableName group by InvoiceID order by Date
```

I'm very new to SQL, can anyone suggest how can i solve that problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want aggregation, but you need an aggregation function for the ordering as well:

```
SELECT InvoiceID, sum(Amount) as Amount 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY InvoiceID 
ORDER BY MIN(Date);
```